# Idiomatic Ruby filter for nil-or-empty?

Tags: ruby, idioms, enumerable

I'm looking for a more idiomatic way to filter out nil-or-empty elements of an array.

I have many methods of the form:

```rb
def joined
    [some_method, some_other_method].compact.reject(&:empty?).join(' - ')
end
```

This will take the result of `some_method` and `some_other_method` and return only the one(s) that are both non-nil (`compact` is essentially equivalent to `reject(&:nil?)`) and non-empty.

Is there anything in Array or Enumerable that gets the same thing in one shot?

Comment: with activesupport yes, with core Ruby no.

Comment: your method really should not care about whether there are blank values in the array or not. Candidate for refactoring!

Comment: @padde Why shouldn't it care?  The array is only created in the method to avoid repeating code.  And the filtering is the whole raison-d'être for the function(s): take whichever of X and/or Y is non-nil and non-blank and do something with them (in the sample, join them with a hyphen).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Rails, you can do `reject(&:blank?)`, or equivalently, `select(&:present?)`.

If this is not for a Rails app, and you do this a lot, I'd advise you to define your own helper on `String` or whatever else you are filtering.

```
class String
  alias :blank? :empty?
end

class NilClass
  def blank?
    true
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. [ActiveSupport's blank?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F) was what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

The following code should do the trick:

```
[some_method, some_other_method].reject{|i| i.nil? || i.empty? }
```

It could be easily used to extend the array class:

```
class Array

  def purge
    self.reject{|i| i.nil? || i.empty? }
  end 

end
```

And then you can just do:

```
[some_method, some_other_method].purge
```

Comment: This version is longer than the version I posted in the initial question, which defeats the point.

Comment: Your version is 69 chars, whereas @Eric's version is only 64 chars.

Comment: The `.join(' - ')` in my version, which shows an example of what it might be used for, bumps his to 76.

Answer (score 2):

monkeypatches accepted? :)

you can try this:

```
class Array
  def tight
    self.compact.reject { |i| i.size.zero? }
  end
end

p [nil, 1, ''].tight
#=> [1]
p ['', nil, 2].tight
#=> [2]
```

it will work with any objects that responds to `size`, not only with ones that respond to `empty?`

Comment: You can improve `== 0` to `zero?`. By the way what are the classes that respond to `size` and not respond to `empty?`?

Comment: `zero?` is a good improvement, however `== 0` is more readable/usable to me. Fixnums does not respond to `empty?`.

Comment: I think to most people `zero?` is more readable. Furthermore, it is faster than `== 0`.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps we need but one simple extension to NilClass?

```
class NilClass
  def empty?
    true
  end
end
```

Comment: +1 smallest footprint; can also extend Fixnum with expression `self == 0` amongst others

Answer (score 0):

@trans enjoyed my +1 but after further deliberation I've reached the following conclusion.

If we go on the premise that everything is an `Object` then all we actually need is a patch to `class Object`

```
class Object
    def empty?
        self == 0 or not self
    end
end
```

Which satisfies my requirement:

```
1.9.3 :001 > d=[Object.new, Class, {a:nil}, 'a', '', [], 1, 1.1, 0, 0.0, 0x0, 0E0, true, false, nil]
 => [#<Object:0x007fd56c086918>, Class, {:a=>nil}, "a", "", [], 1, 1.1, 0, 0.0, 0, 0.0, true, false, nil] 
1.9.3 :002 > d.reject(&:empty?)
 => [#<Object:0x007fd56c086918>, Class, {:a=>nil}, "a", 1, 1.1, true]
```

What about yours? Do we need something more? Please state your qualms or show silent agreement by voting up to help motivate a language change upstream.

nJoy!

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to use `reject` method. Simply use Array's `select` method.

```
def joined
  [some_method, some_other_method].select { |method| method.present? }
end
```

Or even better:

```
def joined
  [some_method, some_other_method].select(&:present?)
end
```

For more **[Idiomatic way to write Ruby code](https://medium.com/the-renaissance-developer/idiomatic-ruby-1b5fa1445098)**, you should read this [article](https://medium.com/the-renaissance-developer/idiomatic-ruby-1b5fa1445098)

Comment: `select(&:present?)` is mentioned in the first line of the answer I accepted in 2012, and as pointed out then, it's [added by ActiveSupport](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F).

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveSupport`, part of Rails, has this method, and so does the `blank_empty_nil_filters` gem: `is_blank?` and `is_empty?`.

There is a distinction between the two.  Some use-cases tolerate blanks (whitespace), some do not.

Perhaps most importantly, filtering out these kinds of values from Hash and Array values is already built-in to `blank_empty_nil_filters`.  Examples:

```
array.no_nil_values
array.no_empty_values
array.no_blank_values
```

See the [README](https://github.com/aks/blank_empty_nil_filters#readme)

`ActiveSupport` a much larger, more comprehensive gem, uses `Regexp.match` to determine blankness, while the `blank_empty_nil_filters` gem code uses a non-destructive strip, which is both faster and less sensitive to non-UTF8 string error conditions.